# What is a public object module in VBA?

Tags: oop, vba, excel

I'm trying to get as close to function pointers / abstract classes as I can in VBA.

I have a class called `VerificationManager` and verifies a bunch of cells in a couple of spreadsheets match up.  This will be done in different ways depending on the information and spreadsheets being used with it.

I'd like to be able to make the code reusable by specifying a method to be called in a string using the `Application.Run` function.  So I can rewrite the function that changes.

Now if I was using Java or C# I would be able to extend an abstract class and rewrite the internals to the function.  If I was using JavaScript I could store a function in a variable and pass the variable to the class and call it from there.

Inside my class I have a public property called "verificationModule" which I set to the name of the function I want it to call.

```
Sub VerifyWorkLocations(empLoc As EmployerLocation)
...
    For i = 0 To empLoc.numOfEmp
        Application.Run verificationModule, empLoc.taxdescmatch, empLoc.employees(i)
    Next i
...
End Sub
```

However, when I try to call `Application.Run` I receive the following error:

> Compile Error:
>
> "Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be
>   coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions"

I already tried placing my User Defined Types in a `Class Module` but it basically said that a class module was the wrong place for a type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error comes from full-fledged VB, where you can create an ActiveX dll project, create a public class there and put a UDT into that class.

In VBA, you use classes instead of UDTs when you need to coerce to or from a variant.

So just declare a class with all the fields you have in your UDT, and delete the UDT.

Alternatively, create a DLL in VB6 that would only contain the declaration of the type, and reference that dll from VBA. Or, if you're comfortable with IDL, just create a TLB file directly.

Answer (score -2):

To add a module to a VBA application, try the following steps (assuming you've already entered the VBA IDE):

1. From the Project Explorer, right-click on your project.
2. Click on "Insert..."
3. Select "Module."
4. If no modules exist, a new folder within the VBA/Excel project will be created, named "Modules," and a module with a default name of "Module1" will be created.
5. Double-click the module to open it in the source editor.

This is where you have to place UDT's. I believe this is because of the difference in the way such types are stored internally by VBA relative to the COM-style structure of elements/objects declared/manipulated as Classes...

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that's what I did when I created all the modules for the project.  Is there something else here I'm missing?

Comment: Where did you put the UDT? As a test, I just put a sample UDT at the top of a module created as described above, and it seems to have worked just fine...

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding the problem, and do you want to migrate your UDT's into full-fledged Classes in VBA?

Comment: I just want to get rid of the error message and keep coding... ;)  This is mostly a throw away project that I'm using to test the output of a query.

Comment: Well, I'll just offer that I could put a UDT in the module as shown/illustrated above, so I'd offer you might give this a try or rework your UDT's as classes...

Comment: @DavidW Add the following in your `Sub main()`: `Dim v as variant: v = xxx`. Same happens when you try to call `Application.Run` with parameters that are UDTs.